# Status of SQL-query

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I want to know, if the SQL-query was executed succesful. In C# I execute the query like this:

```cs
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<placeholder>"))
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table", conn);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    // Get status of query
}
```

How do I get the status of the query, that is executed successful or maybe with an error?

Comment: [Documentaton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) - always a good starting point.

Comment: if an error occurs, an exception will be raised in your application.

Comment: You can test it by running this query: `SELECT 1/0 as MyCoolError`

Comment: Side note: `command` and `reader` need `using` blocks

Answer (score 1):

If `ExecuteReader` returns then it succeeded. If it doesn't succeed then it will throw an exception. You should be catching the possible exceptions, just as you should for any code that can reasonably an exception. I'm not going to go into that here because that's a subject in itself that you should become familiar with.